# Trapezium responsive Div with CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I have to build this website and I am faced with a unique challenge of alternating Trapezium Divs. I have never come across anything like this before and I have no idea how to achieve this. To make things more complicated, this is going to be a responsive website.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: [Meet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) [CSS](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) [triangles](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles).

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Any research done? Relevant websites found? Any idea at all? Your question does not show a lot of effort so far, adding what you already know will help with the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the SkewX transform to skew a div's before element:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  z-index:1;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
div:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text here</div>
```

---

You could do this for many different trapeziums:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background: blue;
}
div {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
div:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
.left {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.right {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">Some Text saying</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="left">how much I love the</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="left right">MINIONS!</div>
```

Comment: Haha, I didn't know you could actually do "color: tomato"

Comment: @FrederikWitte: see [here](http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html) for more named colors.

Answer (score 0):

## SVG

If you define multiple trapzoids in svg you can reuse them inside divs to get the shape you desire.
Defining a template of shapes makes the shapes reusable.
To reuse them simply define a **<use xlink:href="#targetid">** element

```css
.example {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="template" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <def>
    <polygon id="trapzoid" points="0,20 100,0 100,100 0,80" />
    <polygon id="trapzoid2" points="20,0 80,0 100,100, 0,100" />
  </def>
</svg>

<div class="example">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="#trapzoid" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="#trapzoid2" />
  </svg>
</div>
```