# How do you create a responsive rectangle with a triangle corner, which angle does't change?

Tags: css, css-shapes, shapes

I was wondering how I could create a rectangle, which corners angle doesn't change when the elements total width changes.

Example by the two images below: Different widths, but the corner thingy stays the same.

To clarify: the angle is -20 degrees.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693128/trapezium-responsive-div-with-css-or-jquery/29693941#29693941) [also linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879793/how-to-achieve-a-trapezoid-in-css3/28940620#28940620)

Comment: and a [demo, just for you](http://jsfiddle.net/auq0p7fo/) (note. requires prefixing)

Comment: So you want it to go from -20degrees to something like -40degrees? Change it in the media query. 20 degrees is always 20 degrees. Your image example shows exactly that.